# Load Form Dropdown Options Based on Logged In User

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have 2 tables, subcontractors and users.

Each table has a column named "district".

I have a question in my form in which I want the user to select a district. I want the form to show the dropdown options of "district" based on the "district" of the user that is logged in.

When I code my model with my "$this->session->userdata" code the dropdown options just show up blank.

When I put in the code to specify the "district" then the dropdown box works correctly and only shows the district options from the subcontractors table.

My objective is for the form dropdown to only show the options that match the same district as the user that is logged in.

FOR EXAMPLE: When "James" is logged in, when he's filling out the form, I want every "sub_name" that has the same "district" as james to show up in a dropdown box.

[image]

[image]

There will be about 30 different users using the system so each user that logs in will need to see a different set of district variables when they log in.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

--

**MODEL** (does not work - dropdown options show up blank)

```
    public function get_subcontractors()
    {
        $this->db->where('district', $this->session->userdata('district'));
        $query = $this->db->get('subcontractors');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**MODEL** (DOES work - form dropdown shows only the options with the same district id)

```
    public function get_subcontractors()
    {
        $this->db->where('district', 'cobb');
        $query = $this->db->get('subcontractors');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$data['subcontractors'] = $this->Page_model->get_subcontractors();
```

**USER/LOGIN** (controller)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function index()
    {
        // Check Login
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
            redirect('admin/login');
        }

        $data['users'] = $this->User_model->get_list();
        // Load templte
        $this->template->load('admin', 'default', 'users/index', $data);
        // referencing <!-- /application/views/admin/users/index.php -->

    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[4]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //Load View Into Template
            $this->template->load('admin','login','users/login');
        } 
        else 
        {

            // Get Post Data
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $enc_password = md5($password);

            $user_id = $this->User_model->login($username, $enc_password);

            if($user_id)
            {
                $user_data = array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id, 
                    'username' => $username, 
                    'district' => $district, 
                    'logged_in' => true
                );

                // Set Session Data
                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

                // Create Message
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You are logged in');
                
                // Redirect to pages
                redirect('admin');

            }
            else
            {
              $this->session->set_userdata('district', $loaded_login['district'])
              
              
                // Create Error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Login');
                
                // Redirect to pages
                redirect('admin/users/login');

            }

            // Add Activity $this->Activity_model->add($data);

        }

    }



    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('user_id');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
        $this->session->sess_destroy();

        // Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You are logged out');

        // Redirect
        redirect('admin/users/login');
    }
    
  
  
  
}
```

**USER_MODEL** (login)

```
    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return $query->row()->id;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**ADMIN NAVIGATION WRAPPER**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
<?php echo $username = $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>
<span class="caret"></span></button>


<?php $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>
<?php if( $user_id == '3' ):?>
      
      <!-- START FULL NAVIGATION -->
```

**VIEW**

```
<select name="sub_name" class="form-control name_list" >
     <option value="NA">Choose</option>
        <?php foreach($subcontractors as $subcontractor) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $subcontractor->sub_name; ?>"><?php echo $subcontractor->sub_name; ?> 
     </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: what is the output of `echo $userdistrict;` in the first model after the variable is declined?

Comment: It just comes up blank

Comment: concerning your last edit, please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316137/what-to-do-when-op-offers-payment-for-solution and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty

Comment: This will have to be 1 question (of many) at a time... I hope - $this->session->set_userdata('district', 'loaded_login['district']'); has a typo and where is $loaded_login? coming from?

Comment: Someone told me to add the $loaded_login to the code, but I've now deleted it. Where do you see the typo?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw see my answer, i suggested him this line with fake code where he had to replace `loaded_login['district']` with the way he accesses his login return database row, but unfortunatly he got me wrong and took it literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

1). User_model.php

Replace login function with this function.

```
public function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

2). Register.php

and this is index function in your register.php

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[4]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //Load View Into Template
            $this->template->load('admin','login','users/register');
        } 
        else 
        {

            // Get Post Data
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $enc_password = md5($password);

            $result = $this->User_model->login($username, $enc_password);

            if($result)
            {
                $user_data = array(
                    'user_id' => $result[0]['id'], 
                    'username' => $username,
                    'district' => $result[0]['district'],
                    'logged_in' => true
                );

                // Set Session Data
                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);              

                // Create Message
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You are logged in');
                
                // Redirect to pages
                redirect('admin');

            }
            else
            {
                // Create Error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Login');
                
                // Redirect to pages
                redirect('admin/users/login');

            }



        }

    }
```

Try this solution, i hope this will work

Comment: Thank You! This worked PERFECTLY!! Now I'm able to utilize the -- $this->db->where('district', $this->session->userdata('district')); -- within my model file which in turn allows me to only show options in the dropdown menu based on the logged in user's "district" ID matching the "district" of the items available to be added to the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the Session data in your login controller:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('district', 'loaded_login['district']'); // replace loaded_login['district'] with your implemented access to that data
```

for testing purpose you could do:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('district', '2 peachtree');
```

**Edit:**

I would suggest you to change the return value of `$this->User_model->login($username, $enc_password);` to return the whole user data row instead of just the user_id. After that you can do this:

```
...
$user_row = $this->User_model->login($username, $enc_password);

        if($user_row )
        {
            $user_data = array(
                'user_id' => $user_row['id'], 
                'username' => $user_row['user_name'], 
                'district' => $user_row['district'], 
                'logged_in' => true
            );

            // Set Session Data
            $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

            // Create Message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You are logged in');
            
            // Redirect to pages
            redirect('admin');

        }
...
```

**Edit 2:**

Ah i see. You are working with object return types from you database. With

```
return $query->row()->id;
```

(in User_model login method) you only return the id of your database login row. But the `row()` stores all information of your database row, also the district value. And you need that district value to be safed in your session data, so that you can let your website behave user specific. Therefore you return the whole row instead of just the id, and write the whole row information into your session. So we change this line to

```
return $query->row();
```

Then in your user login Controller do this:

```
...
$user_row = $this->User_model->login($username, $enc_password); //here we now get the whole database row as object

        if($user_row )
        {
            $user_data = array(
                'user_id' => $user_row->id, //now you can access each database field to a variable in your session
                'username' => $user_row->user_name, 
                'district' => $user_row->district, 
                'logged_in' => true
            );

            // Set Session Data
            $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

            // Create Message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You are logged in');
            
            // Redirect to pages
            redirect('admin');

        }
...
```

Comment: @RobertoRaymon when you login, you get a row from your table `users`. You need to access the field value `district` of that row at that position.

Comment: When I add -- 
                $this->session->set_userdata('district', $loaded_login['district']); --  or even --  $this->session->set_userdata('district', '2 peachtree');-- my dropdown options still show up blank.

Comment: Hey @RobertoRaymon, if you want to load user specific data, you need a login functionality. Typically you have a login form that requires username / passwort input. If a user types in correct login data, you want to store his user data into the session.

Comment: Just added my login fine

Comment: @RobertoRaymon i edited my answer. If you need help on "return the whole user data row instead of just the user_id" please post your `$this->User_model->login($username, $enc_password);` method code

Comment: If I change to your "$user_row" edit how would I recode my admin/navigation? -- <?php echo $username = $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>
 -- and -- <?php $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>
 --

Comment: @RobertoRaymon Updated my answer. The access in your admin/navigation stays the same.